# Magento 2 Update URL key with SQL update

Tags: magento2, database

Is there any way to update URL Keys with SQL? I have thousants of wrong URL keys.
If not any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

I found it myself. Its very easy to do though the Magento 2 Importer in the System Tab.

Generate a file with data like

```
sku,url_key
12345,newurlkey
23456,newurlkey2
```

Where 12345 is you SKU and newurlkey is your new URl Key. 
And choose update/add.

After that reindex through ssh:

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```